# Connect to WSL running on Win11 VM via Visual Studio Code tunnel

Tags: visual-studio-code, tunnel, remotes

I have VSCode running on a remote Windows VM, that I use for developing on WSL.

When I connect via RDP to the VM, I switch to WSL by choosing it as a remote.

I now started using the Tunnel remotes and I set up a tunnel to connect to VSCode on the VM from my laptop.

How can I connect directly to the VS Code devserver running on WSL on the remote machine?
It seems that even if I set up the tunnel when connected to the WSL remote, I still only set up the tunnel for the Windows instance of vscode (the prompt is Windows, not Linux).